# could not found bean for MongoRepository (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am using `spring boot` and `MongoDB`.

```
Spring version : 4.3.9

Spring boot version : 1.5.4
```

I am creating a repository which implements `MongoRepository` `interface`, like below

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface HotelRepository extends MongoRepository<Hotel,String> {
}
```

But, whenever I am adding a dependency to HotelRepository compiler giving the error `Field hotelRepository in com.demo.HotelController required a bean of type 'com.demo.HotelRepository' that could not be found.`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hotel")
public class HotelController {

    @Autowired
    private HotelRepository hotelRepository;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Hotel> getAllHotels(){
        return this.hotelRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

I've examine all the aspects from my side to resolve the error but all in vain. What I've R&D.

- For `HotelRepository` there will be a default implementation provided out of the box. [as per spring docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/)
- I've annotated the interface with `@Repository`, so no need to put `@Component`
- Adding dependency from spring context using `@Autowired` annotation, So it should pick created bean from spring context.
- All the required files are in the same package, so no need to put `@ComponentScan`

Here is my main spring boot application class :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MongoWithBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MongoWithBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties :**

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=HotelDB
```

**Stack trace** :

```
2017-07-10 13:25:12.485  INFO 4712 --- [           main] com.demo.MongoWithBootApplication        : Starting MongoWithBootApplication on KELLGGNCPU0313 with PID 4712 (D:\STS_WS\MongoWithBoot\target\classes started by mehrajuddin.malik in D:\STS_WS\MongoWithBoot)
2017-07-10 13:25:12.487  INFO 4712 --- [           main] com.demo.MongoWithBootApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-07-10 13:25:12.519  INFO 4712 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@13acb0d1: startup date [Mon Jul 10 13:25:12 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-10 13:25:13.448  INFO 4712 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-07-10 13:25:13.456  INFO 4712 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-07-10 13:25:13.456  INFO 4712 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2017-07-10 13:25:13.541  INFO 4712 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-07-10 13:25:13.541  INFO 4712 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1025 ms
2017-07-10 13:25:13.635  INFO 4712 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-07-10 13:25:13.637  INFO 4712 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-10 13:25:13.638  INFO 4712 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-10 13:25:13.638  INFO 4712 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-10 13:25:13.638  INFO 4712 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-10 13:25:13.673  WARN 4712 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hotelController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'hotelRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.demo.HotelRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2017-07-10 13:25:13.675  INFO 4712 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-07-10 13:25:13.684  INFO 4712 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-07-10 13:25:13.737 ERROR 4712 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field hotelRepository in com.demo.HotelController required a bean of type 'com.demo.HotelRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.demo.HotelRepository' in your configuration.
```

**pom.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>MongoWithBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MongoWithBoot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Could someone please help me out here what am I missing?

Comment: Please share your source-code Application class.

Comment: Add `@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "your.repository.package")` annotation to your configs

Comment: Can you post the detailed stack trace as well?

Comment: @StanislavL I am not using any Java Based configuration, just using application.properties

Comment: @JaydeepRajput I've added the stack trace.

Comment: The add the annotation right after the `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: What spring version are you using?

Comment: Try removing @Repository annotation (as the example you gave does not have it)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Faced similar problem, Adding the following to Application class helped me resolving the problem

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = DeviceDataRepository.class)
```

In your case it could be

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = HotelRepository.class)
public class MongoWithBootApplication{ ... }
```

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same problem

Used below code to scan mongorepository packages

```
@SpringBootApplication                                                       
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"//packages you want to scan for activiting mongo repositories"})
public class SpringBootMongoDBApp{ ... }
```

It resolved my problem

Answer (score 3):

we need to activate mongo repositories using `EnableMongoRepositories`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories //specify packages to scan
public class MongoWithBootApplication{ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. It fixed the issue for 1.4.1-RELEASE of spring boot.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same structure and I just had to add this configuration:

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    ...
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/hotelDB
```

And the repository package have to be in a deeper level of Application.java class. Thats all

```
com.hotelDB
    Application.java
    repository (Package)
    controller (Package)
    service (Package)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

After so much of struggle, finally I've resolved the problem.

There is nothing wrong in the code or annotation. **The problem was spring boot's version**.

However, I am still not sure what is the wrong in the version above `1.5.1.RELEASE` .If anybody knows the root cause can edit or answer the question.

**Problem** : If I add `spring-boot-starter-parent` above `1.5.1.RELEASE`, it gives me the above no bean error for `MongoRepository`. It gives error from `1.5.2` to `1.5.4` version. (`1.5.4` was the last version till that I've tried and faced the no bean error)

**Solution** : It runs fine if I add `spring-boot-starter-parent` `1.5.1.RELEASE` or below (`1.5.0` was lowest version till I've tried).

Answer (score 0):

Just tried and did not found any problem at all with my existing spring boot mongodb project with `1.5.4.RELEASE` for `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

Earlier it was configured with `1.4.0.RELEASE`.