# Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am following this tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hu-cyytqfp8 ) and trying to connect to MongoDB on a remote server in Spring Boot. 
I get the following message when I run the application.

> Description: Parameter 0 of constructor in com.mongotest.demo.Seeder
>   required a bean of type 'com.mongotest.repositories.StudentRepository'
>   that could not be found.
>
> Action: Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.mongotest.repositories.StudentRepository' in your configuration.

The project structure.

[image]

And here are my classes

```java
    @Document(collection = "Students")
    public class Student {

        @Id
        private String number;
        private String name;
        @Indexed(direction = IndexDirection.ASCENDING)
        private int classNo;

    //Constructor and getters and setters.
    }

    ================================

    @Repository
    public interface StudentRepository extends MongoRepository<Student, String>{

    }

    ================================

    @Component
    @ComponentScan({"com.mongotest.repositories"})
    public class Seeder implements CommandLineRunner{

        private StudentRepository studentRepo;

        public Seeder(StudentRepository studentRepo) {
            super();
            this.studentRepo = studentRepo;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Student s1 = new Student("1","Tom",1);
            Student s2 = new Student("2","Jerry",1);
            Student s3 = new Student("3","Kat",2);
            studentRepo.deleteAll();
            studentRepo.save(Arrays.asList(s1,s2,s3));

        }

    }

    ================================

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.mongotest</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>demo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>


    </project>
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45012168/3344829, can you try spring boot version `1.5.1` or less

Comment: I tried 1.5.1.RELEASE and 1.5.0.RELEASE... still not working

Comment: we need to activate mongo repositories using `@EnableMongoRepositories`, please see the answer

Comment: Try annotating the StudentRepository class with `@Service`. I saw this on another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993124/the-injection-point-has-the-following-annotations-org-springframework-beans/59994805#59994805), and this worked for me.

Comment: @Lycanthropeus a Repository is not a Service, maybe it should be annotated as `@Repository`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please add below annotations in `DemoApplication`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.mongotest") //to scan packages mentioned
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.mongotest") //to activate MongoDB repositories
public class DemoApplication { ... }
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation please?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to avoid writing annotations you can simply change your packages `com.mongotest.entities` to `com.mongotest.demo.entities` and `com.mongotest.repositories` to `com.mongotest.demo.repositories`

Spring Boot architecture will take care of rest. Actually other files and packages are supposed to be either at same level or below your `DemoApplication.java`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case , I was getting same error using mysql db

solved using ***@EnableJpaRepositories***

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.repositories")//to scan repository files
@EntityScan("com.example.entities")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repositories")
public class EmployeeApplication implements CommandLineRunner{ ..}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 helper classes RedisManager, JWTTokenCreator & JWTTokenReader which I needed to pass in constructor as dependency of SessionService spring service.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationServiceApplication {
  @Bean
  public SessionService sessionService(RedisManager redisManager, JWTTokenCreator tokenCreator, JWTTokenReader tokenReader) {
    return new SessionService(redisManager,tokenCreator,tokenReader);
  }

  @Bean
  public RedisManager redisManager() {
    return new RedisManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public JWTTokenCreator tokenCreator() {
    return new JWTTokenCreator();
  }

  @Bean
  public JWTTokenReader JWTTokenReader() {
    return new JWTTokenReader();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(AuthenticationServiceApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

The service class is as follows

```
@Service
@Component
public class SessionService {
  @Autowired
  public SessionService(RedisManager redisManager, JWTTokenCreator 
      tokenCreator, JWTTokenReader tokenReader) {

      this.redisManager = redisManager;
      this.tokenCreator = tokenCreator;
      this.jwtTokenReader = tokenReader;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the annotation you defined.

@ComponentScan("com.mongotest")

This will scan all the relevant packages under the project structure 'com.mongotest' and initializes the beans in all the subpackage classes.

Answer (score -3):

```html
@Document(collection = "Students")
public class Student {
 
 @Id
 private String number;
 private String name;
 @Indexed(direction = IndexDirection.ASCENDING)
 private int classNo;

//Constructor and getters and setters.
}

================================

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends MongoRepository<Student, String>{

}

================================

@Component
@ComponentScan({"com.mongotest.repositories"})
public class Seeder implements CommandLineRunner{

 private StudentRepository studentRepo;
 
 public Seeder(StudentRepository studentRepo) {
  super();
  this.studentRepo = studentRepo;
 }

 @Override
 public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  Student s1 = new Student("1","Tom",1);
  Student s2 = new Student("2","Jerry",1);
  Student s3 = new Student("3","Kat",2);
  studentRepo.deleteAll();
  studentRepo.save(Arrays.asList(s1,s2,s3));
  
 }

}

================================

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

Comment: ThIs doesn't work at all.