# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.java.floatcare.service.serviceName' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have tried all available solutions on the internet but it's not working.

Tried Solutions like this:

> [Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240271/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-in-your-configuration)

Here is my code:

```
import com.java.floatcare.model.TestCollection;

@Autowired
private TestCollectionService testCollectionService;

public TestCollection createTestCollections(Long userId, String userName, Long userType, Long businessAddress, Long businessAddress2, String phoneNumber, String email, String status)throws Exception {
    return testCollectionService.createTestCollections(userId, userName, userType, businessAddress, businessAddress2, phoneNumber, email, status);
}

public TestCollection updateTestCollections(Long userId, String userName, Long userType, Long businessAddress, Long businessAddress2, String phoneNumber, String email, String status)throws Exception {
    return testCollectionService.updateTestCollections(userId, userName, userType, businessAddress, businessAddress2, phoneNumber, email, status);
}

public boolean deleteTestCollections(long userId) {
    return testCollectionService.deleteTestCollections(userId);
}
```

Error:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.java.floatcare.service.serviceName' in your configuration
```

Comment: Adding the full error description with stacktrace will help you get the answer faster

Comment: You could rephrase your question to start with what you are trying to achieve. You could also share more about the problem (looks like an extract at the moment)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field testCollectionServices in com.java.floatcare.resolver.mutation.MutationDefault required a bean of type 'com.java.floatcare.service.TestCollectionService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.java.floatcare.service.TestCollectionService' in your configuration.